# TreeView ContainsKey not working during add loop

Tags: vb.net, treeview, refresh, treenode, containskey

I've been reviewing the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.containskey(v=vs.110).aspx) and reading posts on the subject but still have not found the answer

```
currentTREENODE = treeviewResults.TopNode


        For Each item As String In incomingList

            If treeviewResults.Nodes.ContainsKey(item) Then

                currentTREENODE = treeviewResults.Nodes.Find(item, True)(0)

            Else

                newNode = New TreeNode(item)
                newNode.Name = item

                currentTREENODE.Nodes.Add(newNode)

            End If

        Next
```

I was thinking at first that the Collection wasn't being updated immediately so I tried BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate(), Update(), Refresh() but this has not corrected the problem

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You arent using `nextTREENODE` anywhere, just assigning it

Comment: cleaned it up some more

Comment: *What are you trying to do?*  Its not going to do anything if the node already exists (the IF portion isnt needed).  TopNode is the first visible node, not the root node, is that what you want?  The key is not the same as the text, so it might look like it fails.

Comment: I did not realize that containskey does not check child nodes.  Do you see any reason why treeview.nodes.find(item,true) would not work to determine if a treenode already exists?

Answer (score 0):

Treeview.nodes.find works best, now I just need to figure out how to do it with a partial name or wildcards